# Custom Action DLL dependent on another DLL

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, custom-action

Does anyone know of a way to include a DLL so that my custom action dll can use it as it is dependent on it. I just need a way to have the DLL bundled into the MSI and to be unpacked into the temporary installation folder along with the custom action DLL. If it's there, then the custom action DLL will be able to find it and thus will be able to run.

I have read on-line to add it as a reference and set the copy local property top true but it does not seem possible, if there is another way I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is it an option to statically link the dll to avoid the runtime dependency? I have done this several times before by setting compiler options in Visual Studio.

Comment: What is this custom action doing? Can it run deferred (system context) or does it deal with userprofile or user data locations?

Answer (score 0):

The WIX Toolset allows you to create managed (.net) custom actions using its Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) feature. An entire visual studio solution can be output to a single dll, ready to be embedded in the binary table of an MSI. At runtime everything gets unpacked and executed automatically. This has been a life saver for me, as it allows you to create extremely powerful custom actions very easily (standard warnings about not doing foolish things in custom actions apply here). The DTF approach is very elegant, easy to use, and works reliably.

Since you presumably already have a working custom action dll, maybe you could create a small DTF custom action that invokes methods in your existing dll? If your dll can be referenced by a .net assembly this should be possible. When you build the custom action project in visual studio it should suck up all the references and pack them into the output dll.